# Xcode: signing issue : certificate installation failed (ver. 8.2.1)

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode8, code-signing-certificate

I'm getting the below error, when I'm trying to sign the sample project:

> > Certificate installation failed
> >     Installing a certificate in the keychain failed (Error Domain=DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-61 "write permissions error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=write permissions error})

**Where exactly does XCode not have permission to write to ?**

[image]

I get the same error when I press **reset** in the view details page popup shown below
[image]

***Edit**
Modified the **bundle_identifier** and now I see a new error.
I wonder if I should revoke !

> > Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain. To create a new one, you must first revoke the existing certificate.

Comment: FYI - I have changed the bundle-id. And see this error now: Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain. To create a new one, you must first revoke the existing certificate.

Comment: "Where exactly does XCode not have permission to write to" The keychain. If that error message is telling the truth, that's the first place that needs attention. Use Keychain Access application (in _/Applications/Utilities_) to see what's going on. You certainly can't add a certificate if you have keychain permission issues.

Comment: Thanks @matt - in keychain I that the "FileVault Master Password Key" has expired, but I doubt that is used to sign code.

Comment: I see a "software signing" cert. which is valid till 2021. There aren't any issues I see.

Comment: Revoked & back to the original issue. How do I give XCode permission to the keychain..

Comment: I would have to say that your keychain, your Xcode prefs, or your entire user is hosed. My suggestion: make a new admin user, log into it, launch Xcode (Xcode _must_ be in the top-level _/Applications_ folder, remember), and go to the Accounts pref pane and try to configure things there. If it works, at least you know this can be done; it might then be simplest to migrate everything into this new user and abandon the old one. (Please note, though, that your use of FileVault introduces complications I am not acquainted with.)

Comment: Thanks @matt that resolved it ! Adding all my steps for anyone else in the same boat.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks for reporting back. Sometimes it's just easier to create a new user than to try to "solve" the problem. It would still be good to try to "solve" it but I'm not sure how. It might involve blowing away the keychain...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @matt.
Here is what I did -

- Created a completely new admin profile on the computer
- In Xcode, added the account by going in to XCode -> preferences
- In the "General" tab for the project, added my profile
- As soon as I switched the profile from "None" to mine - Xcode created the certificates
- I then got this error "There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it."
- Plugged in my phone, and changed the target from simulator to my own phone
- That resolved it & had the app. on my phone :) !!